# How I getting array data in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift

For example:

```
var score = [51,67,73,103,47,98,83,78,61]
```

< 60 = Fail

60-70 = D

71-80 = C

80-90 = B

91-102 = A

here's the work that I tried

```
var score = [51,67,73,103,47,98,83,78,61] 
for score in score 
{ 
  if score < 60
  { 
    print("fail") 
  } 
  if score > 60 && score < 70 
  {
     print("D")
  } 
  if score > 70 && score < 80 
  {
    print("C")
  } 
  if score > 80 && score < 90 
  { 
    print("B")
  }
  if score > 90 && score < 102 
  { 
    print("A")
  } 
}
```

How to I get the final result as

```
score = [Fail,D,C,A,Fail]
```

something like that

I'm new and learning this, Thanks.

Comment: I believe you can perform checking based on conditions required. Please show us your work. What have you done so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be more precise when you write code. Your array of integers has a different number than the example output you want. I thought perhaps you wanted a set for a response, but there were two fails in there, so I ruled that out, too.

Another source of imprecision are the ranges you specified. You need to keep those tight so there's no overlap. Without any further ado, you need to read up on `map`, `filter`, and `reduce`. For what I think you're trying to do, you want to take a string and convert it to an array of grades based on specified ranges. For this, I would use `map` with a `switch`.

```
// Declare a var and use map to look at 
// each Int in the array and return a string
var grades = scores.map { score -> String in
    // each score goes through this switch and returns a String
    switch score {
    // 91 and greater returns "A"
    case 91...:
        return "A"
    // 80 to less than 91 returns "B"
    case 80..<91:
        return "B"
    // 70 to less than 80 returns "C"
    case 70..<80:
        return "C"
    // 60 to less than 70 returns "D"
    case 60..<70:
        return "D"
    // 0 to less than 60 returns "Fail"
    case 0..<60:
        return "Fail"
    // Everything else returns a blank string.
    default:
        return ""
    }
}


// ["Fail", "D", "C", "A", "Fail", "A", "B", "C", "D"]
print(grades)
```

Have a peek at [UseYourLoaf.com's](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-guide-to-map-filter-reduce/) post on `map`, `filter`, and `reduce`.

For the control flow, I used a `switch` statement. You can read more about them in [Apple's Documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Adrian, the result of the code are the one that I wanted, its look difficult for me now :c
I trying to understand about the `switch` statement, Thanks!

Comment: I added comments to the code to explain what's going on. If it answers your question and does what you want it to, please click checkmark on the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Adrian :D